# How to delete hash elements inside a function using scalar variable in perl

Tags: perl, hash

I'm facing one issue while deleting a hash key using scalar variable from another function. So I have a hash like -

```
%larmhash = ('EntityValidation' => 'arm.account.tqLedgerDataRef.xml', 'Functions' => 'arm.billing.fUtilities_Integer.xml', 'EntityValidation' => 'pcom.cnCustomer.exp');
```

I'm passing this hash to another function and inside the other function I'm iterating through the hash keys and inside a switch case I'm trying to delete any key-value pair if the key is not *Functions* type key

This is how I'm trying to do

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use Switch;

sub zBuildHash (\%) {
    my $lhash = shift;
    my @lvalue;

    while (my ($key) = each(%$lhash)) {
        switch($key) {
            case 'Functions' {
                # Do something here
            }
            else {
                # Delete the key-value from the hash
                delete $lhash->{$key};
            }
        }
    }
}

sub zPrepareEntityPurgeHash {
    my %larmhash = ('EntityValidation' => 'arm.account.tqLedgerDataRef.xml', 'Functions' => 'arm.billing.fUtilities_Integer.xml', 'EntityValidation' => 'pcom.cnCustomer.exp');

    zBuildHash(%larmhash);
    print Dumper(%larmhash);
}
```

In the above code at the end of zBuildHash() function call, when I print the hash inside zPrepareEntityPurgeHash(), I should only get ('Functions' => 'arm.billing.fUtilities_Integer.xml')

Basically I want to call the hash by reference and delete any key if I don't want in the original hash. Can someone help me with where am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with `switch` but if I use a normal  `if`/`else` it seems to work as expected. You'd need `print Dumper(\%larmhash);` to get `'Functions' => 'arm.billing.fUtilities_Integer.xml'` though.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of deleting all the other keys, make a hash with the keys that you know that you want. This is easy with the new [hash chunk slice](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2014/07/perl-5-20-introduces-keyvalue-slices/). These slices return the key and value instead of just the value:

```
use v5.20;
my @keep = qw(Functions);
my %new_hash = %existing_hash{@keep};
```

You can even assign back to the hash you started with:

```
use v5.20;
my @keep = qw(Functions);
%existing_hash = %existing_hash{@keep};
```

This works when you know the keys. If you are looking for patterns or other things you have compute, you'd need to do something more sophisticated.